# How to return this crazy type in Dart?

Tags: dart, mongo-dart, dart-mock

I am trying to mock the .find function in mongo_dart and it is asking for a return function that I just can't work out. It has a type, then another type, then the name. What / how do I express this return type.

This is legitimate code apparently:

```dart
Stream<Map<String, dynamic>> Function([selector]) _test(Invocation realInvocation) {
}

class selector {
}
```

Returning a `Stream<Map<String, dynamic>>` throws an error - it says it needs a *`Stream<Map<String, dynamic>> Function([selector])`*

Help! I have never seen anything like it and Google isn't much help.

---

Edit, thanks to Irn's comment below, the solution ultimately was this code. See their answer and the comment I made for clarification

```dart
Stream<Map<String, dynamic>> Function([dynamic]) _test(Invocation realInvocation) {
  return ([selector]) {
    return Stream.value({"response":true});
  };
}
```

Comment: It returns a **function**.  That returned function takes an optional `selector` argument and returns a `Stream<Map<String, dynamic>>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type is `Stream<Map<String, dynamic>> Function([selector])`.
That's the type of a *function*. A function declaration with that type could be:

```dart
Stream<Map<String, dynamic>> createMaps([selector s]) async* {
  ... do something ...
    yield map;
  ... do more ...
}
```

The `[selector]` part means that the function must accept one optional positional parameter with the type `selector` (which *really* should be capitalized to make it clear that it's a type).
The `Stream<Map<String, dynamic>>` means that the function returns a stream.

So, since `_test` returns such a function, you could write test as:

```dart
Stream<Map<String, dynamic>> Function([selector]) _test(Invocation realInvocation) {
  return createMaps; // But should probably use realInvocation for something.
}
```

(That would make the type of `_test` be:

```dart
Stream<Map<String, dynamic>> Function([selector]) Function(Invocation)
```

which is a mouthful!)

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Just for anyone in the future, the syntax is for a closure - so a function that returns a function (which returns an object of a type Stream). Obvious with @lrn's help.